# How to move the master bone of a rig to the actual pose?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, makehuman

I have just started animating with Blender. Now I have a question:

I have imported a MakeHuman Model of a person with the default rig. After that I posed the rig and created a stand up animation. So first, I moved my model in object mode to the start position and rotated it by 90 degrees. Then I made the animation, at the end of the animation the model stands next to the bed.
This works fine, **but** ...

Now the model stands there, but the master bone of the rig is still at the original position.

*So how can I move the master bone to the rest of the rig, **without** changing the pose or the location of the model?*

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never move the rig in object mode, you want to use the Root/Master bone exactly for this and also you never move the rig away from the Root/Master.

The reason is when you only animate bones, you get only 1 Action. Whereas when you animate also the object you get 2 Actions and it's messy. Can be problem when the rig is linked and you need to apply animations to the proxy. You also can't save such pose to pose library. Etc. this can go on and on why not to do it.

There is no easy way of fixing it. You will have to investigate what bones are parented to the Root/Master, move those bones back and position everything with the Root. And if you have animation do it for every keyframe.

If you have lots of keyframes it might be better to bake the animation. You do this by creating and parenting an empty to each bone that is parented to Root(local axis should correspond). You then bake animation to the empties. Then you move (and animate) the Root where you want it and override the transforms of parented bones with Copy transforms constraints from the empties. Then you bake the animation to the bones and you delete the empties.

Comment: I didn't animate the object in object mode, I just moved the model to the starting position in object mode. The position of the origin never changes.

Comment: @Erich If you move something in object mode the origin changes. What you said doesn't make sense. Can you clarify? Maybe with a picture?

Comment: I meant, during the animation the origin never changes.

Comment: @Erich Oh, ok, if you don't have any keyframes then your job is much much simpler. You just need to re-arrange things so the Master is at the right place and everything has correct translations/rotations. To do this exactly/precisely you can use helper empties to remember where things were when re-arranging.